# equivalent of http-proxy-option custom header on openvpn

Tags: http-headers, http-proxy

i want to know if exist the equivalent of these openvpn options on nginx(or squid/privoxy):

```
http-proxy my.VPS.IP.server 8080
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER X-Online-Host custom.website
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER Host custom.website
```

i can't find anything clear for me.

What i want:

(instead of set a custom header in openvpn i want to set it directly on vps on nginx or squid so i'll could have it also using other vpn protocol.)

example
:

- i set a custom header blabla.com
- then i connect to my vpn and  i make a request to g00gle.com
- my ISP have to know that i'm surfing on blabla.com but instead i have access to g00gle.com

That happens with the http-proxy-option that i write at the top of this post.

It's possible to do it  or OpenVPN is the only one to make it possible?